# Exec stored procedure with OPENQUERY with parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, openquery

I have the following procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[meals] @EncounterID nvarchar(15), @EventDate nvarchar(30)
AS
   DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000);

   SELECT  @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(cerner, ''select ce.result_val  PercentEaten,
ce.event_cd Meal
 from clinical_event ce
 where
 ce.task_assay_cd in ( 5362408, 5362296, 5361870)
 and ce.event_end_dt_tm >= sysdate-30
 and ce.event_cd in (636033, 636036, 636039)
 and ce.event_class_cd = 233
and ce.encntr_id = ''' +CAST(@EncounterID as varchar(15))+ '''
and ce.event_end_dt_tm between to_char('''+CAST(@EventDate as varchar(30))+''' - .5) and 
    to_char('''+CAST(@EventDate as varchar(30))+''' - 1)
'')';
EXEC (@TSQL);
GO
```

When I execute with this line:

```
exec dbo.meals @EncounterID =  '12345678',@EventDate = '07/18/2013'
```

I get an error that just says `error at line 9`

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Your openquery wrapper should be fine (apart from indenting it). Problem is in your wrapped query (`select ce.result_val  PercentEaten...`) and I bet it's somewhere in quotes....

Comment: I tried additional quotes around both variables and the error moves to the date variable

Comment: Can you post the actual and complete error message?

Comment: Try removing `and ce.event_end_dt_tm between ...` clause and run to diagnose it. When testing, maybe you should consider adding TOP 1 if you get too many results.

Comment: It works without the clause but the date is important.  are multiple parameters possible?

Comment: the error message is:  Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Line 10: Incorrect syntax near '07'.

Comment: Great, you should have told that it is Oracle on the other side...

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I can conclude following:

1. Check if you really have to_char() function on the `cerner` side. If you don't have it, that's the error's all about.
2. Instead `CAST(@EventDate as varchar(30))`, try to convert it like `CONVERT(varchar(30), @EventDate, 111)` (if you need time as well, change **111** to **120**)

**EDIT**

Obviously you have to use Oracle syntax in openquery. It should be something like...

```
AND ce.event_end_dt_tm between to_date ('2013/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') and to_date ('2013/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

So, point #2 should be your solution, with a bit different Oracle function calls.

Complete AND clause:

```
...
and ce.event_end_dt_tm between to_date(''' + CONVERT(varchar(30), @EventDate, 111) + ''', ''yyyy/mm/dd'') - 1 and to_date(''' + CONVERT(varchar(30), @EventDate, 111) + ''', ''yyyy/mm/dd'') - 0.5
```

**Note**: I didn't understand how those dates make any sense, so I inversed the order of *from* and *to* dates.

Comment: I cannot use CONVERT because the Cerner database is Oracle. I have to send Oracle syntax, right? EDIT - I see what you mean now.  I will try that.

Comment: Ok, I tried removing TO_CHAR, got the exact same error.  I tried CONVERT, got the exact same error.

Comment: This part `CONVERT(varchar(30), @EventDate, 111)` executes on SQL Server side, not Oracle

Comment: Error message is still the same.  Is it possible to use the EventDate parameter in the initial select statement?

Comment: I don't really get the question with the *initial* query; however, can you try just one thing... `and ce.event_end_dt_tm between to_date(''2013-07-01'', ''yyyy/mm/dd'') - 1 and to_date(''2013-07-01'', ''yyyy/mm/dd'') - 0.5` ?

Comment: the error message is now Incorrect syntax near '2013'. My question was can I add the EventDate parameter in the select from OPENQUERY. Something like Select Evendate from OPENQUERY.... ') where @EventDate bETWEEN....

Comment: Of course you can do `select @EventDate from OPENQUERY...`, but that way you are selecting scalar value same for all rows

Comment: Another idea: could you remove the EXEC part? That way you would avoid overquoting, which I think is a problem here